# Trying to make a submit button in another file update a table in another file without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

[image: My Webpage]

Here are my three classes:
This class is where i combine the other two classes.  When i press submit i was the table on the right to update without refreshing.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>BugDisplayAndReport</title>
            <script src = "jquery.js"></script>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $.post('BugReport.html',{},function(data){
                        $("#BugReport").html(data);
                    });
                });
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $.post('BugDisplay.php',{},function(data){
                        $("#BugDisplay").html(data);
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id = "BugReport"></div>
            <div id = "BugDisplay"></div>
        </body>
    </html>

Here is the Issue Report code, i am not going to use the "location.reload(true)" to do what i want because i would the the page to update without refreshing:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>IssueReport</title>
        <script src = "jquery.js"></script>
        <style>
            body{
                padding:0;
                margin:0;
            }
            #box {
                padding: 5px;
                color:black;
                margin: 0 auto;
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: black;
                border-width: 1px;
                width: 162px;
                float: left;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#sub").click(function(){
                    var user_issue = $("#issue").val();
                    var user_priority = $("#priority").val();
                    var user_type = $("#type1").val();
                    $.post("BugReport.php",{issue:user_issue,priority:user_priority,type1:user_type},function(data){
                        $("#result").html(data);
                        //location.reload(true);
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="box">
        <h3 style = "margin:10px 30px 30px 30px">Issue Report</h3>
        <form action="BugReport.html" method="post">
        <textarea cols="20" rows="18" name="issue" id = "issue" placeholder = "Enter Your Issue Here" "></textarea></form><br>
        <div style = "width: 100px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">Type Of Issue:</div>
            <div style = "width: 150px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding: 2px">
            <form action="BugReport.html" method="post">
            <select name = "type1" id = "type1">
                <option value = "Listing Discrepancy">Listing Discrepancy</option>
                <option value = "PO Discrepancy">PO Discrepancy</option>
                <option value = "Pricing Discrepancy">Pricing Discrepancy</option>
                <option value = "Program Glitch">Program Glitch</option>
                <option value = "Receiving Discrepancy">Receiving Discrepancy</option>
                <option value = "RMA Discrepancy">RMA Discrepancy</option>
                <option value = "Sales Discrepancy">Sales Discrepancy</option>
                <option value = "Shipping Discrepancy">Shipping Discrepancy</option>
            </select>
            </form></div>
            <div style = "width: 50px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">Priority:</div>
            <div style = "width: 70px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding: 2px">
            <form action="BugReport.html" method="post">
            <select name = "priority" id = "priority">
                <option value = "Low">Low</option>
                <option value = "Regular" selected>Regular</option>
                <option value = "High">High</option>
                <option value = "Urgent">Urgent</option>
            </select>
            </form></div>
        <div style = "width: 50px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding: 2px">
        <input type ="submit" name = "sub" value = "Submit" id = "sub"></div>
        <div id="result"></div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the code that creates the table on the right:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $database = "database";

    $con = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$database);

    if($con->connect_error){
        die("Connection failed " . $con->connect_error);
    }

    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM BugReport where priority = 'Urgent'";
    $strSQL1 = "SELECT * FROM BugReport where priority = 'High'";
    $strSQL2 = "SELECT * FROM BugReport where priority = 'Regular'";
    $strSQL3 = "SELECT * FROM BugReport where priority = 'Low'";
    $rs = mysqli_query($con,$strSQL);
    $rs1 = mysqli_query($con,$strSQL1);
    $rs2 = mysqli_query($con,$strSQL2);
    $rs3 = mysqli_query($con,$strSQL3);
    $i = 0;
    echo "<table style = 'float: left; position: relative; left:160px; border: 1px; border-style:solid; border-collapse: collapse;'><tr>
    <th style = 'border: 1px; border-style:solid; border-collapse: collapse;'>Priority</th>
    <th style = 'border: 1px; border-style:solid; border-collapse: collapse'>Issue Category</th>
    <th style = 'border: 1px; border-style:solid; border-collapse: collapse;width: 300px'>Issue</th>
    <th style = 'border: 1px; border-style:solid; border-collapse: collapse;'>Date</th></tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)){
        if(($i % 2) == 0){
            echo '<tr style="border: 1px; background:#CCFF33; color: black">';
        }else {echo '<tr style="border: 1px; background:white; color: black">';}
        echo "<td style = 'border: 1px; border-style:solid; border-collapse: collapse;'>" . $row['priority'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td style = 'border: 1px; border-style:solid; border-collapse: collapse;'>" . $row['type1'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td style = 'word-break:keep-all;width: 300px; border: 1px; border-style:solid; border-collapse: collapse;'>" . $row['issue'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td style = 'border: 1px; border-style:solid; border-collapse: collapse;'>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
        echo '</tr>';
        $i = $i + 1;
    }
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs1)){
        if(($i % 2) == 0){
            echo '<tr style="border: 1px; background:#CCFF33; color: black">';
        }else {echo '<tr style="border: 1px; background:white; color: black">';}
        echo "<td style = 'border: 1px; border-style:solid; border-collapse: collapse;'>" . $row['priority'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td style = 'border: 1px; border-style:solid; border-collapse: collapse;'>" . $row['type1'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td style = 'word-break:keep-all;width: 300px; border: 1px; border-style:solid; border-collapse: collapse;'>" . $row['issue'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td style = 'border: 1px; border-style:solid; border-collapse: collapse;'>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
        echo '</tr>';
        $i = $i + 1;
    }
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs2)){
        if(($i % 2) == 0){
            echo '<tr style="border: 1px; background: #CCFF33; color: black">';
        }else {echo '<tr style="border: 1px; background:white; color: black">';}
        echo "<td style = 'border: 1px; border-style:solid; border-collapse: collapse;'>" . $row['priority'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td style = 'border: 1px; border-style:solid; border-collapse: collapse;'>" . $row['type1'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td style = 'word-break:keep-all;width: 300px; border: 1px; border-style:solid; border-collapse: collapse;'>" . $row['issue'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td style = 'border: 1px; border-style:solid; border-collapse: collapse;'>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
        echo '</tr>';
        $i = $i + 1;
    }
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs3)){
        if(($i % 2) == 0){
            echo '<tr style="border: 1px; background:#CCFF33; color: black">';
        }else {echo '<tr style="border: 1px; background:white; color: black">';}
        echo "<td style = 'border: 1px; border-style:solid; border-collapse: collapse;'>" . $row['priority'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td style = 'border: 1px; border-style:solid; border-collapse: collapse;'>" . $row['type1'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td style = 'word-break:keep-all;width: 300px; border: 1px; border-style:solid; border-collapse: collapse;'>" . $row['issue'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td style = 'border: 1px; border-style:solid; border-collapse: collapse;'>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
        echo '</tr>';
        $i = $i + 1;
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @JayBlanchard - `When i press submit i was the table on the right to update without refreshing` - edit - beaten by a whisker

Comment: Is the second file on the server? Or being displayed in a browser?

Comment: @JayBlanchard the second file is on the server

Comment: If you want to update a file on the server you have to AJAX to a PHP process which will open the file, rewrite it and then save it.